# Restore default signals to QgsVectorLayer using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, pyqt5, signal

I have a connected a function to the [QgsVectorLayer.selectionChanged](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/core/QgsVectorLayer.html#qgis.core.QgsVectorLayer.selectionChanged) signal of one of my layers.

For the sake of simplicity let's assume it is a simple print statement:

```py
def print_confirmation():
    print('selection has been changed')

lyr = iface.activeLayer()

lyr.selectionChanged.connect(print_confirmation)
```

Is there a way to restore the layer to its default signal state,  *without* explicitly disconnecting the function?

```py
lyr.selectionChanged.disconnect(print_confirmation)
```

It is possible to indiscriminately disconnect all signals with:

```py
lyr.selectionChanged.disconnect()
```

however, this can interfere with the default behaviour of the layer and cause unwanted effects.

Comment: I *highly* doubt it as I would be very surprised if Qt somehow would track any connections made and their historical state. Sounds like a XY problem, what are you really trying to achieve? :)

Comment: adding to @bugmenot123's comment - the qt documentation even states the following: Just as an object does not know if anything receives its signals, a slot does not know if it has any signals connected to it. Therefore I believe there is no way track all connections. The only information you can get on signal connections is how many slots are connected: `lyr.receivers(lyr.selectionChanged)`

Comment: Admittedly, there is an element of XY to it, but in the interests of finding a workaround. Basically, I have a more complex situation where I connect a function with arguments using `lambda` but this function cannot be disconnected, I think because the lambda version is an instance of the function and not a reference to the function itself.

Comment: @Matt For lambda slots you can retrieve the Connection object and use it to disconnect the slot. `conn = lyr.selectionChanged.connect(lambda: print_confirmation())` and then `lyr.selectionChanged.disconnect(conn)`  to disconnect.

Comment: @CodeBard, many thanks, that is very useful. In the end I rewrote my function without arguments (using class attributes instead) as I was experiencing crashes when trying to disconnect. I will certainly remember this for future, though.